# What are these random mushrooms in my garden?

Tags: fungus, mushrooms

I check the garden every day for pests and to water, but seemingly overnight these random mushrooms (or whatever they are) have sprouted up. Is this dangerous? What are they? And why are they there?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]